# Use generic type in class constructor

Tags: c#

I have an Interface and an Abstract class with its derived one:

```
  public interface IIndicator<TInput, TOutput> { } 

  public abstract class Indicator<TInput, TOutput> : IIndicator<TInput, TOutput> {

    public abstract TOutput Calculate(TInput input);

  }

  public class MyIndicator : Indicator<Decimal, Decimal?> {

    public MyIndicator(IEnumerable<Decimal> inputs) {
      // Code using base.Calculate and inputs
    }

    public MyIndicator(IEnumerable<Decimal> inputs, Func<TMapper, Decimal> mapper) {

      // Code using base.Calculate, inputs and mapper 

    } 

    public override TOutput Calculate(TInput input) {
      // Implementation of Calculate
    }

  }
```

The problem is that TMapper is not defined in the contructor:

```
public MyIndicator(IEnumerable<Decimal> inputs, Func<TMapper, Decimal> mapper, Int32 period)
```

I would like to use MyIndicator as:

```
MyIndicator indicator = new MyIndicator(inputs, x => x.Id)
```

Instead of:

```
MyIndicator<MyClass> indicator = new MyIndicator<MyClass>(inputs, x => x.Id)
```

Where `MyClass` would be something like:

```
public class MyClass { 
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You simply need to specify `MyClass` instead of `TMapper` because there's nothing else it can be with the syntax you want.

Comment: It won't happen unless you specify a constructor argument that represent the object of the `MyClass` and should appear before the Mapper lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a factory method instead e.g.

```
public static MyIndicator Create<TMapper>(IEnumerable<decimal> inputs, Func<TMapper, decimal> mapper, int period)
{
    var indicator = new Indicator(inputs);
    // do stuff with your mapper / period
    return indicator;
}
```

Comment: Typo I guess, but I think you meant `Create<TMapper>(...)`.